# Firebase rules: enable write on a specific node only for one user uid

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm trying to enable only the user with "wYr5TO3QhzMIyUK8hj5jAmGE7u53" uid to be able to write to the payements node (see code below). Is that possible?

This is my code:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
      ".write": "auth !== null && !newData.hasChild('payement')"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. To allow a single UID to write the `payement` node, use:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "payement": {
      ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === 'wYr5TO3QhzMIyUK8hj5jAmGE7u53'"
    }
  }
}
```